# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'shape' at noise = np.random.normal(0, 20, file_name.shape)

Tags: python, arrays, string

**The code:**

class Encryptor:

```
I = np.asarray(PIL.Image.open("D:\Fall 2021\Secure comm\Python\Project\mona.jpeg"))

noise = np.random.normal(0, 20, I.shape)
new_signal = I + noise
imageio.imwrite('mona_noise.jpeg', new_signal.astype(np.uint8))

def __init__(self, key):
    self.key = key

def pad(self, s):
    return s + b"\0" * (DES.block_size - len(s) % DES.block_size)

def encrypt(self, message, key, key_size=256):
    message = self.pad(message)
    iv = Random.new().read(DES.block_size)
    cipher = DES.new(key, DES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    return iv + cipher.encrypt(message)




def encrypt_file(self, file_name):
    noise = np.random.normal(0, 20, file_name.shape)

    new_signal = file_name + noise

    with open(file_name, 'rb') as fo:



        plaintext = fo.read()
    enc = self.encrypt(plaintext, self.key)


    with open(file_name + ".enc", 'wb') as fo:
        fo.write(enc)
    os.remove(file_name)



def decrypt(self, ciphertext, key):
    iv = ciphertext[:DES.block_size]
    cipher = DES.new(key, DES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    plaintext = cipher.decrypt(ciphertext[DES.block_size:])
    return plaintext.rstrip(b"\0")

def decrypt_file(self, file_name):
    with open(file_name, 'rb') as fo:
        ciphertext = fo.read()
    dec = self.decrypt(ciphertext, self.key)
    with open(file_name[:-4], 'wb') as fo:

        fo.write(dec)
    os.remove(file_name)
```

**The Error:**
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\mmahi\PycharmProjects\Project\DESIMG.py", line 82, in 
enc.encrypt_file(str(input("Enter name of file to encrypt: ")))
File "C:\Users\mmahi\PycharmProjects\Project\DESIMG.py", line 37, in encrypt_file
noise = np.random.normal(0, 20, file_name.shape)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'shape'

Comment: You're calling `encrypt_file` with a string, which does not have the attribute `shape`... You can't use `file_name.shape` and input a string.

Comment: how can I fix it?